# Does openfire server implements the Mine capability?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am trying to find out if the openfire implements the Mine capability. The mine-ing simply means sending multiple xmpp message to all resources linked to a specific JID.

Therefore I have sent an IQ query using smack. According  to (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0259.html#disco_server) if i send

```
<iq type='get'
from='romeo@montague.net/orchard'
id='info1'>
<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>
</iq>
```

I should get

```
<iq type='get'
to='romeo@montague.net/home'
from='montague.net'
id='info1'>
<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'>
...
<feature var='urn:xmpp:tmp:mine:0'/>
...
</query>
</iq>
```

Nevertheless i do not get any feature with such property. Does this mean simply that openfire does not have this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't. This extension is also in "deferred" state.

Alex

Comment: Which only means that the XEP wasn't updated since 12 months: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0001.html#states-Deferred 
The XEP is still on the standards track and seems very useful.

Comment: This use case will probably be more widely solved/implemented by XEP-280: Message Carbons.